# A question about Indian English usage

Tags: discussion

I think this is a very interesting [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410345/does-the-phrase-pass-out-also-mean-to-graduate) about a BrE  expression mainly confined to  military usage  which has gained traction on a more popular basis in India. OP appears to be at a loss after having  checked with Google and asked around.

Is putting the question on hold the best way to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably the only one who voted to leave it open, and that's probably because I'm an Indian myself, and I understood what OP was thinking. The question does not include research much, but I must say that it's not easy for such an OP to find the right sense from google results.

Your answer is neat, and I don't think it'll need any additional answers. Regardless, I've voted to reopen.

Now that ELU has an answer to it, [it's the top google result for others to see](https://www.google.com/search?q=Does%20the%20phrase%20%E2%80%9Cpass%20out%E2%80%9D%20also%20mean%20%E2%80%9Cto%20graduate%E2%80%9D).